# Expect to automate yes answer to CLI

Tags: linux, shell-script, expect

When I run the command `ambari-server upgrade` from a bash script, in the middle of the upgrade we get the question

> have made a backup of the Ambari Server database [y/n] (y)?

so we want to automate the process, by expect script that will send `yes` when the question comes.

Please advice how to automate the `ambari-server upgrade` by expect

```
ambari-server upgrade

Using python  /usr/bin/python
Upgrading ambari-server
INFO: Upgrade Ambari Server
INFO: Updating Ambari Server properties in ambari.properties
...
WARNING: Can not find ambari.properties.rpmsave file from
previous version, skipping import of settings
INFO: Updating Ambari Server properties in ambari-env.sh ...
INFO: Can not find ambari-env.sh.rpmsave file from previous
version, skipping restore of environment settings. ambari-env.sh may not
include any user customization.
INFO: Fixing database objects owner
Ambari Server configured for Embedded Postgres. Confirm you     

have made a backup of the Ambari Server database [y/n] (y)?

INFO: Upgrading database schema
INFO: Return code from schema upgrade command, retcode = 0
INFO: Console output from schema upgrade command:
INFO: {"lzo_enabled":"false"}
INFO: Schema upgrade completedAdjusting ambari-server permissions and ownership...
Ambari Server 'upgrade' completed successfully.
```

Comment: Does `yes |  ambari-server upgrade` do the job?

Comment: yes , like charm

Comment: One of the keys to successful expect programming is knowing when expect is actually ridiculous overkill. This example and connecting to remote machines with ssh are problems that don't need to be solved with expect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can pipe `yes` into your script:

```
yes | ambari-server upgrade
```

This will cause every prompt to be replied to with `y`.

Comment: well done great solution